# Unable to save CustomKeys.txt for WarCraft using WarKeys

Tags: technical-issues, warcraft-3, warcraft-3-the-frozen-throne

I'm trying to configure custom keys through WarKeys, the WarCraft 3/DOTA Custom Keyboard shortcut mapping tool and getting an error when I try to export my mappings. I went through and modified the defaults and then selected "Save to CustomKeys.txt" and get the error message below. Now I have Warcraft installed on a different drive and at first thought it might the way I named the path, but I also tried changing it without the symbols but it still showed the same message. Help?

[image: error message]

Comment: I know this is an older version, but I originally used the latest version and had no success, upon hunting for a solution I found a forum where someone used an older copy to extract most of the DOTA settings that WarKeys provides.

Comment: I know it doesnt solve your issue but for dota i used : http://www.drjones.dk/customkeys/generator.php this website that allow you to do exactly the same thing

Comment: Thanks. I also found this but problem with it is I'm trying to generate custom keys for Warcraft 3 not DOTA.

Comment: Does the path actually exist? If not, just create the folder path and he should save it there. You just need to copy it then to the correct position. Also it was maybe not a good idea to call a folder '-=Games=-', this might cause problems.

Comment: Is your games folder really called `- = Games = -`!?

Answer (score 1):

first of all warkeys are outdated - so I recommend you to use [dota customkeys generator](http://ack.auct.eu/) online
second - save customkeys.txt on desktop or in document folder and then copy it to your warcraft III folder.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about this, but it doesn't appear to give me the option to customize the other wc3 actions that warkeys did. Is there another way?

Comment: yeah=( it's only for dota as I'm a dota player.
and btw I think there are plenty of wc3 customkeys editors

and for guys who want [custom keys for dota 6.79](http://ack.auct.eu/)